# Ways of expressing dislike

Tags: american-english

I have a question on word usage...

> Example: I don't like eating beef.

Is there another word I can use to express the same meaning without using "*don't like*"? For example, would the following sentence be appropriate?

> "I despise eating beef."

If not what would be a better way of saying it please?

Comment: Have a look at a dictionary and look at synonyms for despise, dislike etc. Generally it is expected here to provide some research regarding the topic of your question. You can also visit the help center to find out about good questions.

Comment: "Despise" is much stronger than "don't like".  It is unclear what you mean.  Do you not like the taste, or are you environmentally, ethically or morally opposed to eating beef and/or all meat and/or all food products derived from animals?

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly acceptable to use any of a spectrum of words to convey exactly how strong you feelings are.
"I don't like" is fine, though "I dislike" seems a bit less informal — but that is preference.
"I despise" is equally acceptable if you want to give a more emphatic answer.
"I am repulsed by" might be even a stronger sentiment than "despise", while
"I prefer not to" might be milder than dislike.

Choose the strength of word that fits best for the amount of emotion you want to give.
If you will not under any circumstances eat beef, then "don't like" is probably too weak a statement; but "don't like" would be fine if you will do it to be polite, but would rather have chicken for instance.